# Falco output formation

Tags: kubernetes, falco

I am using runtime detection tool Falco to analyse the container behavior for at least 40 seconds, using filters that detect newly spawning and executing processes store the incident file art /opt/falco-incident.txt containing the detected incidents. I try to format the output result one per line, in the format [timestamp],[uid],[user-name],[processName]

I created the yaml file audit.yaml

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
rules:
- level: Metadata
  namespace: ""
  verb: ""
  resources:
  - group: ""
    resource: ""
  - name: audit
    hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/audit.yaml
      type: File
  - name: audit-log
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/all-resources.log
      type: FileOrCreate
  - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/audit.yaml
    name: audit
    readOnly: true
  - mountPath: /var/log/all-resources.log
    name: audit-log
    readOnly: false
```

I edited the kube-apiserver with adding this 3 lines

```
 - --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit.yaml
 - --audit-log-path=/var/log/all-resources.log
 - --audit-log-maxage=1
```

The main question is: How and where to define the desired output which should look like this ?

[timestamp],[uid],[user-name],[processName]

[timestamp],[uid],[user-name],[processName]

....

Comment: Please provide more details. Are you asking how the default output from the falco can be formatted to the desired one? Or are you asking about k8s audit policy configuration?

Comment: Yes i need to edit the default output  from the falce and format it to this way [timestamp],[uid],[user-name],[processName]

Comment: IT looks like your audit policy is improper, please refer to [Audit policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#audit-policy) especially [Log backend],  [Webhook backend]. In audit.k8s.io/v1 we don't have such parameters like: mountPath, hostPath it should be specified in kube-apiserver yaml file. Please provide used yaml/deployment, current audit events, falco events - preferred in json format. Did you try [program_output] in falco config and pipe the output into [jq](https://falco.org/docs/alerts/#program-output-example-posting-to-a-slack-incoming-webhook)

Comment: Is there a way to print the output in this format   <Time userid/username processname> ? So, the catch here is to print userid/username based on the output availability.   Ex: <time> 1000 vim  \n   <time> jane ps   \n   <time> test netstat   \n  <time> 2000 nc

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going in the wrong direction. The question specifies using Falco tool so you need to edit the falco_rules.local.yaml file. THis has nothing to do with the Auditing policy. It could be something like this:

```
- rule: spawned_process_in_container
  desc: A process was spawned in the container.
  condition: container.name = "pod" and evt.type = execve
  output: "%evt.time,%user.uid,%user.name,%proc.name"
  priority: ERROR
```

And when you try to run you can use the below command for running it 40 seconds

> falco -M 40 -r /etc/falco/falco_rules.local.yaml > log.txt

This will run the falco for 40 seconds with your given conditions and push the result in your desired format to log.txt file.

*P.S: I know this is quite late to answer but someone else might benefit from this.*

Answer (score 0):

The custom rule should be defined in the file etc/falco/falco_rules_local.yaml. Please check the rules already present in etc/falco/falco_rules.yaml and use the same format to define the new rules.

Comment: Is there a way to print the output in this format ?
<Time userid/username processname>

So the catch here is to print userid/username based on the output availability.

Ex:
<time> 1000 vim
<time> jane ps
<time> test netstat
<time> 2000 nc